# Python Lists - find uncommon elements

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy

I want to compare two lists in order to create a new list of specific elements found in one list but not in the other. I want the code to return all occurrences of unmatched values.

input:
list1=7,7,8,9
list2=8,9

desired output= 7,7

```py
import numpy as np
   list1 = input("Input list1 : ").split(",")
    
   list2 = input("Input list list2 : ").split(",")
    main_list = np.setdiff1d(list1,list2)
    print(main_list)
```

Comment: `[i for i in list1 if i in (set(list1) - set(list2))]`

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
[i for i in list1 if i in (set(list1) - set(list2))]
```

using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
np.array(list1)[np.in1d(list1, np.setdiff1d(list1, list2))].tolist()
```